# How can I connect to SQL server with Entity?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following a tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller)

And in there he's using SQL server localdb.
This is my first try with MVC. Last project I did with asp and had no trouble connecting to the database (which runs on a different server)

So how can I connect to my SQL server 2014 using entity? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go in your web.config file
2. Find the connectionStrings section.
3. Setup your connection string to use the sql server 2014

   <
    add name="DefaultString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=YourServer;Database=YourDatabase;UID=YourUserId;PWD=YourPassword;" >

For more information on [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Others

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="(localdb)\mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>


<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Vidly;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>    
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: please explain how this answers the question

Answer (score -2):

Connecting to SQL Db with the help of Entity framework is very easy and interesting.
The link which you are following is incomplete because they haven't shown how to connect with DB
For connecting DB there are multiple ways,In this example i will show you  DB first method.
Create a DB in your SQL server. 
Go to your MVC project -> right click on Models folder -> Add ->ADO.NET entity Data Model -> Enter any name for your Model -> Press Ok -> This will prompt You " Entity Data Model Wizard " -> Select Generate from Database ->  Press Next-> New Connection ->This will prompt you Connection Properties,from here you just select your Database. this is how you can connect with your DB ,These are are steps you have to follow first,then continue with you Tutorial Link.[Connection Properties configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2fS7.png)